# Empty test suite error when running unit test case in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, junit, cassandra

I check out the source code of Cassandra, and I want to run a unit test case in debug mode to understand how it works

Below is my JUnit run configuration set up. The code can compile correctly using ant. And I tried both targets `build` and `build-test`.

[image]

IntelliJ can pick up the class in the run configuration, but when I run this profile, I got.

```
Process finished with exit code 1
Class not found: "org.apache.cassandra.tools.SSTableExportTest"
Empty test suite.
```

What part do I need to change the configuration so that IntelliJ can run this unit test cases?

Comment: Test classes are no compiled because you have removed the Build step from Before launch tasks list. Your Ant build probably produces the files not where IntelliJ IDEA expects them to be.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is compiled since I set Run Ant Target "build-test" before launch. I can see the compiled class in the output build directory.

Comment: Build with IDEA and see if it places the files in the same location.

Comment: The output compiled class path is {project_path}/build/test/classes/org/apache/cassandra/tools/. From the folder name I think it matchs the source code package declartion which is package org.apache.cassandra.tools;

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA default output path is different, so it doesn't see your classes compiled by Ant (`out/test/<modulename>`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're trying to debug Cassandra. You can reference https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/RunningCassandraInIDEA. They have already set up a ant target to generate required configurations.